# Rest JSON Document body

Tags: apex, json

```
{
Name:"name1"
body:"blobbody"
value1:""
value2""
}
```

How do I deserialize the above request so that I can store "body" in Document object and other 3 values in a different object?

Answer (score 1):

First deserialize using and into the classes generated by [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) and then transfer the fields to the various objects and update them in hand written Apex code.

Comment: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string, I'm getting this error whn I try to deserialize a blob

Comment: @cartman If you have written some code using Blob and have this problem I suggest you create another question including that code and the sample JSON.